# How can I get Magento Each Session values by using Magento frontend cookie value through Web Service?

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies, frontend

We are developing separate home page from Magento and accessing information from Magento through Web Services and will integrate this external home with existing Magento website. But on this home page I am facing a problem related to session I have created a frontend cookie on this external home page. But I have no idea how can I get session values by using frontend cookie value.

I am working on this problem from last 1 week please post your valuable answer from which I can resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start a PHP Session
A session is started with the session_start() function.

Session variables are set with the PHP global variable: $_SESSION.

Create a new page called "test_session1.php". In this page, we start a new PHP session and set some session variables:create a page called "test_session.php". From this page, you will access the session information we set on the first page ("test_session1.php").

the session variables are not passed individually to each new page, instead, they are retrieved from the session we open at the beginning of each page (session_start()).

All session variable values are stored in the global $_SESSION variable:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "pink";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "goat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

Get PHP Session Variable Values
```

Create another page called "test_session2.php". From this page, we will access the session information we set on the first page ("test_session1.php").

Session variables are not passed individually to each new page, instead, they are retrieved from the session we open at the beginning of each page (session_start()).

All session variable values are stored in the global $_SESSION variable:

Another way is to print session variables

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
?>

</body>
</html>
```